# writing a dependent type in agda to guarantee a list is sorted

Tags: sorting, agda, dependent-type, agda-stdlib

I have a record type, call if Foo, in Agda.  I can sort it by generating a String representation (display foo) and sorting the resulting strings.  I have a relation, call it `<=Foo`, for comparing Foo records which has one constructor, `$<=Foo$`, that takes evidence `((display a) Data.String.Base.<= (display b))` that the string for `a` is LT the string for `b`.  I've proven it's a DecTotalOrder, yielding fooTotalOrder

I would now like to make a dependent type that enforces that a list is in sorted order.  It seems this should be

`Σ[ l ∈ (List Foo) ] (FooSorted.Sorted l)`

where `FooSorted.Sorted` comes from passing `fooTotalOrder` to `Data.List.Relation.Unary.Sorted.TotalOrder`.

As I understand, to make this work, I need a function, say

`fooSorted : (l : List Foo) -> (FooSorted.Sorted l)`

FooSorted is derived from Data.List.Relation.Unary.Linked.Linked which is defined as

```
data Linked (R : Rel A ℓ) : List A → Set (a ⊔ ℓ) where
    []  : Linked R []
    [-] : ∀ {x} → Linked R (x ∷ [])
    _∷_ : ∀ {x y xs} → R x y → Linked R (y ∷ xs) → Linked R (x ∷ y ∷ xs)
```

Here, R is `<=Foo`.

It seems to me that fooSorted needs to return `Linked <=Foo l` where l is the List Foo argument.

The first two cases are straightforward, but I cannot figure out the last one.  I need to use evidence that `(x <=Foo y)`. I have the constructor for that, but it requires evidence that `((display x) Data.String.Base.≤ (display x))` and I do not see where to get that.

I cannot simply enter that - it won't compile.  From the various ways I can get back a similar type, the closest is using total order, but that returns a sum type and I don't see how to get just the one value from it.

The example I'm trying to imitate, using `isEven`, won't compile if an odd number is used where an even is needed.  I'm looking for the same for lists - the program should not compile if a list is not sorted - but I do want my dependent type to compile.

It's entirely possible I've headed in completely the wrong direction.  Any help is appreciated!

The closest I have come is the following:

```
fooSorted (x ∷ x₁ ∷ m) =  Linked.∷ ($<=Foo$ (getProof x x₁)) (rectype (x₁ ∷ m))
   where
      getProof : (a : Foo) → (b : Foo) → ((display a) Data.String.Base.≤ (display b))
      getProof a b with decLT (display a) (display b)
      ...      | yes P = P
      ...      | no Q = {!  !}
```

The P in the `yes` branch is exactly what I want, but what to put in the other hole?  The intent is that the proof fails.

Comment: The type of `fooSorted` seems false, since not all lists are sorted. Why are you trying to prove this?

Comment: I have routines that require sorted lists. I would like to require the lists be sorted before being passed to those routines.

Comment: So your function should take a list `l` and a witness that `l` is sorted. If you want that to happen automatically (and you can write a procedure that decides whether a list is sorted), have a look at [proof by reflection](https://plfa.github.io/Decidable/#proof-by-reflection).

Comment: What you want is a function `sort : List Foo -> Σ[ l ∈ (List Foo) ] (FooSorted.Sorted l)` which says that, given a list, you can produce a *different* list which is sorted. We call this function "sort" because it produces a list which is sorted and contains the same elements as the input. You cannot reduce this to an applicated of `fooSorted` (which is false as pointed out by others).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the suggestions, and sorry for the delay with a response.  In the end I wasn't able to take advantage of the approach Naïm suggested, which would have worked for strictly static instances.  In the end I needed to follow the last suggestion - which essentially involved reinventing bubble sort.  This way I would eventually end up with the item at the start of the list (let's say a) and use the second constructor from Linked.

Then I would have the next one (say b) of the list and check that b <= a getting b :: a :: [], or create a new list a :: b :: [].

Then as each additional item was added I could check it against its predecessor before adding to the list or recursively sorting its way into the existing list. So, if given a sorted list, this returns a dependently typed sorted list in O(n) time, and otherwise can be O(n^2)

Fortunately, once a list is sorted, all the other operations I wanted to do maintain order.